# MongoDb $geoWithin query on a subdocument

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm trying to do a geospacial query on a subdocument. 
So I have a parent schema that looks like this:

```
var orderSchema = new Schema({
//other properties
venue: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Venue',
}
)};
```

and within my child 'venue' schema I have:

```
location: {
    type: { type: String, default: "Point" },
    coordinates: [Number]
}

venueSchema.index({ "location": "2dsphere" });
```

What Im trying to do is query my order schema directly for a few matching criteria, and also do a $geoWithin query on the venue field. 
I have no problems with this this query executing on the subdocument class directly so Im assuming thats all working properly and the index is set right

```
Venue.find({location : {
        $geoWithin: {
            $geometry: {
                type: "Polygon",
                coordinates: boundry.geometry.coordinates
            }
        }
    }})
```

When I try to query these sub docs from the parent class 'Orders' I don't get any errors, just no matching results:

```
Order.find({'venue.location' : {
        $geoWithin: {
            $geometry: {
                type: "Polygon",
                coordinates: boundry.geometry.coordinates
            }
        }
    }})
```

Im not getting any feedback from execution so Im not sure if this is not supported or I'm doing it wrong.

I have tried to index the child schema on the parent with no luck

```
orderSchema.index({ "venue.location": "2dsphere" })
```

**EDIT**
Parent Im querying:

```
{
  "_id": "5937687f533b9627a4f3afb5",
  "updated_at": "2017-06-07T10:01:26.832Z",
  "created_at": "2017-06-07T02:44:15.561Z",
  "venue": {
    "_id": "586c8da780e0733e124c7710",
    "updated_at": "2017-01-12T22:21:36.190Z",
    "created_at": "2017-01-04T05:52:39.364Z",
    "location_name": "Pizza Shop",
    "location_phone": "(555) 555-555",
    "hours": "11am-12pm Mon - Sat",
    "__v": 0,
    "location": {
      "coordinates": [
        -79.9318376,
        40.4586607
      ],
      "type": "Point"
    },
    "device": {
      "device_type": null,
      "device_id": null
    }
  },
  "receipt_image": null,
  "time": {
    "accepted": "2017-06-07T02:44:20.859Z",
    "picked_up": null,
    "ready_time": null,
    "delivered": null,
    "placed_at": "2017-06-07T02:38:44.556Z"
  },
```

And the particular coordinates passed in at 'boundry.geometry.coordinate' are:

```
[ [ [ -79.99745935177826, 40.43637059697235 ],
[ -79.99773685003227, 40.43631191597255 ],
[ -79.99802046433027, 40.436308499735446 ],
[ -79.99829929553387, 40.4363604795451 ],
[ -79.99856262831626, 40.436465857846585 ],
[ -79.99880034294631, 40.436620585010864 ],
[ -79.9990033041841, 40.4368187149598 ],
[ -79.99916371234308, 40.43705263367056 ],
[ -79.99927540302765, 40.43731335177827 ],
[ -79.99933408402745, 40.43759085003227 ],
[ -79.99933750026456, 40.43787446433027 ],
[ -79.9992855204549, 40.438153295533866 ],
[ -79.99918014215342, 40.43841662831626 ],
[ -79.99902541498913, 40.438654342946315 ],
[ -79.99882728504019, 40.438857304184104 ],
[ -79.99859336632944, 40.43901771234308 ],
[ -79.99833264822173, 40.43912940302765 ],
[ -79.93227424822173, 40.46004010302765 ],
[ -79.93199674996772, 40.46009878402745 ],
[ -79.93171313566972, 40.46010220026456 ],
[ -79.93143430446612, 40.4600502204549 ],
[ -79.93117097168373, 40.45994484215342 ],
[ -79.93093325705368, 40.45979011498914 ],
[ -79.93073029581589, 40.459591985040205 ],
[ -79.93056988765692, 40.45935806632944 ],
[ -79.93045819697234, 40.45909734822173 ],
[ -79.93039951597254, 40.45881984996773 ],
[ -79.93039609973543, 40.45853623566973 ],
[ -79.93044807954509, 40.45825740446614 ],
[ -79.93055345784657, 40.45799407168374 ],
[ -79.93070818501086, 40.45775635705369 ],
[ -79.9309063149598, 40.4575533958159 ],
[ -79.93114023367055, 40.457392987656924 ],
[ -79.93140095177826, 40.457281296972354 ],
[ -79.99745935177826, 40.43637059697235 ] ] ]
```

Comment: Show the document you think should be returning and the actual coordinates you are sending to query.

Comment: @NeilLunn added the geo coordinates and the parent doc

Comment: You have a "referenced" schema, which means the "sub-docs" as you are calling them are actually in a completely separate collection. `$geoWithin` does not actually "require" an index like `$near` does. You "could" in theory do an aggregation pipleline with [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) to join the collections and do the query. However the index you have would not be used, which could be a performance issue.

Comment: As I see it you have three options here. 1. Do the query with `$lookup` to perform the join. 2. Query the collection separately, `.populate()` might even help here. 3. Change the schema to include the location data as "embedded" as opposed to "referenced" so it actually resides in the `Order` model in the first place.